# Display category labels in regression output in R

Tags: r

Using the this [R linear modelling tutorial](http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial1.pdf) I'm finding the format of the model output is annoyingly different to that provided in the text and I can't for the life of me work out why. For example, here is the code:

```
pitch = c(233,204,242,130,112,142)
sex = c(rep("female",3),rep("male",3))
my.df = data.frame(sex,pitch)
xmdl = lm(pitch ~ sex, my.df)
summary(xmdl)
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Call:
lm(formula = pitch ~ sex, data = my.df)

Residuals:
      1       2       3       4       5       6 
  6.667 -22.333  15.667   2.000 -16.000  14.000 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  177.167      7.201  24.601 1.62e-05 ***
sex1          49.167      7.201   6.827  0.00241 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 17.64 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.921, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9012 
F-statistic: 46.61 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.002407
```

In the tutorial the line for Coefficients has "sexmale" instead of "sex1". What setting do I need to activate to achieve this?

Comment: If I copy/paste the code above, I also get "sexmale". Have you tried this in a new R session?

Comment: Yes, you're right it does. I think the line in my old session that caused this is "options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))" from another tutorial I was using.

Comment: Yes, if you globally change the contrast settings, different things will happen. The normal default is `c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly")`

Comment: Thanks I'll look those up and understand what they do.